# "User already registered" when signing in to Azure API Management Developer Portal with Azure Subscription Administrator

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

I have Azure AD and Microsoft identity configured successfully on in my APIM instance.
When I try to directly sign in with either identity provider to the Developer Portal (https://*myapim*.portal.azure-api.net/) of my APIM with the administrator account (which owns the Azure Subscription where APIM resides), the sign up screen is displayed and when I hit "sign up" I get:

```
User already registered
It seems a user with this email is already registered in the system. If you forgot your password, please try to restore it or contact our support team.
```

I currently have not found a way to get around the sign up step, even when I hit sign in again I get re-routed to sign up.

Signing in to Azure Portal first and then navigating across to Developer Portal just works fine - no sign up flow is invoked.

one remark: my MSA owning the Subscription is also linked into my AAD, therefore I could sign in with either way

Comment: I could reproduce this issue too and I am trying report it internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used a functional/group account as APIM administrator - one we never would use to actually log on - then I was able to regularly login with my own account again.

Comment: Do you have to make a new API Managemente instance for that? I am using Azure AD right now and have one user left in the legacy User/Password system that I cannot delete - the administrator. I can not log in with it as login is disabled for this system. I can not login with my Azure AD account as the email is taken...

Comment: Oh, tough question/situation. If I remember correctly we managed with an ARM re-deployment of our APIM instance.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to make a proper ARM template for the instance anyway so guess I will take "advantage" of the situation.

Comment: :-) we absolutely were in the same situation